# Haskell - no output from within StateT monad

Tags: haskell

Trying to familiarize myself with monad transformers, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
data GlobalState = GlobalState {
        rng :: StdGen 
}

foo :: IO ()
foo = 
        evalStateT ( StateT $ 
                   \s -> 
                   let (v, newrng) = roll $ rng s in 
                         return (putStrLn $ show v, 
                                 s { rng = newrng })
        ) zeroState >>
        putStrLn "See you soon."

zeroState :: GlobalState
zeroState = GlobalState {
        rng = mkStdGen 0
}

roll :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
roll gen = randomR (1, 6) gen
```

The idea was to initialize state, use it for an IO action and return back to plain IO afterwards. Something, however, goes wrong and only "See you soon" gets printed, `putStrLn $ show v` produces no output.

So the question is: how do I fix it and, most importantly, **why** doesn't it print anything?

Edit: thank you everyone for your answers, they help a lot.

Comment: I think if you name and give a type to your `StateT` value it may make the issue clearer. `return (putStrLn ...)` is returning an action that *when evaluated* will print something, but then you throw it away when you use `>>`.

Comment: That is, `evalStateT ... zeroState` has type `Monad m => m (IO ())`; it needs to have type `IO ()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my humble opinion, monad transformers are easier to work with if you use the mtl typeclasses. This also leads to more general code since it doesn't tie you to any concrete data type. Also, I would recommend usually separating the "what to do" part from the "run" part. I've rewritten your code to hopefully demonstrate what I mean:

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad.State

data GlobalState = GS { rng :: StdGen }

zeroState = GS { rng = mkStdGen 0 }

roll :: StdGen -> (Int,StdGen)
roll = randomR (1,6)

-- works with any concrete monad m that supplies IO and GlobalState state
foo :: (MonadIO m, MonadState GlobalState m) => m () 
foo = do
  (v,gen) <- gets (roll . rng)
  liftIO $ print v
  put $ GS gen

 -- commit to StateT here
 evalFoo :: IO ()
 evalFoo = evalStateT foo zeroState
```

The benefit is that `foo` is now reusable. For example, if we wanted to roll multiple times:

```
 evalFooN :: Int -> IO ()
 evalFooN n = evalStateT (replicateM_ n foo) zeroState
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is, that you seem to have mistaken the type of `StateT` for `(m a, s) -> StateT s m a`, when actually it is `m (a, s) -> StateT s m a`. That is the `m` is outside and not inside of the tuple. That is why you had to use `return`, to return something of type `IO (a,GlobalState)`. What you have to do instead is something along the lines of `putStrLn (show v) >> return ((),s {rng = newrng})`. Like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import System.Random

data GlobalState = GlobalState {
                   rng :: StdGen 
                 }

foo :: IO ()
foo = evalStateT (StateT $ 
        \s -> let (v, newrng) = roll $ rng s in 
          putStrLn (show v) >>
          return ((),s { rng = newrng })
      ) zeroState >>
      putStrLn "See you soon."

zeroState :: GlobalState
zeroState = GlobalState {
            rng = mkStdGen 0
          }

roll :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
roll gen = randomR (1, 6) gen
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to use `join` to reduce the `IO (IO ())` value returned by `evalStateT` to a `IO ()` value.

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = 
        (join (evalStateT ( StateT $ 
                   \s -> 
                   let (v, newrng) = roll $ rng s in 
                         return (putStrLn $ show v, 
                                 s { rng = newrng })
        ) zeroState) >>
        putStrLn "See you soon."
```

A more complicated, but cleaner, fix is to make sure you don't introduce a new `IO` action in the state itself, but simply include a string which you wrap yourself.

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = 
        evalStateT ( StateT $ 
                   \s -> 
                   let (v, newrng) = roll $ rng s in 
                         return (show v, s { rng = newrng })
        ) zeroState >>= putStrLn >>
        putStrLn "See you soon."
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP intended to do. What he wants is use `IO` from within `StateT s IO a`, and not return a `IO` value and then execute it.

Comment: Type-wrangling aside, I'm not sure I see the difference. I guess he could use `Debug.Trace.trace` instead of `putStrLn`?

Comment: The difference is, that OP tries to understand Monad transformers and your solution doesn't even use the transformer part. You could just as well replace `StateT s IO` with `State s` in your code. And `trace` isn't something you want to use outside of debugging (if you were serious about that).